# passing the self instance of class to another class, from that class, java

Tags: java, class, parameter-passing, instance

how can I pass the instance of the class I am in to another class?  what I am trying to do is not working, there must be a better way.

```
 public class MainExample{

      // constructor
      public MainExample(){

      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {

      MainExample mainCl = // how to get instance of this class?

      NextClass nextCl = new NextClass(mainCl);  // not working, what to pass?           

      }

 }

 public class NextClass {

      MainExample mainEx;

      // constructor
      public NextClass(MainExample me){
      mainEx = me;

      }
 }
```

<<< EDIT >>>

the reason for this is that I have to pass the current instance of MainExample class to NextClass so that I can attach the observer to the observable. using observer pattern.  NextClass will launch multiple threads, one thread for each socket connection.  multiple clients. so I have to;

```
  observable <-- (class instance of class that extends observable class)
  obsever <-- (class instance of class implementing observer)

  using the addObserver method;

  observable.addObserver(observer)
```

Comment: What is MainClass? MainExample?

Comment: Why can't you create an instance of `MainExample` with the constructor?

Comment: Which error are you getting? There is any particular reason for the NextClass class to be defined inside the MainExample class?

Comment: use this operator to get instance of own class...

Comment: typing error in my question, it is all MainExample,   MainClass is not used as name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this: `MainExample mainCl = new MainExample();`

Your `NextClass` constructor expects a `MainExample` reference.

The line `NextClass nextCl = new NextClass(mainCl);` should compile now.

Answer (score 2):

Within the `main` method, there *is* no instance of `MainClass` until you create one, because it's a `static` method.

Within an *instance* method you could use `this`, but in your case you just need to create an instance of `MainExample` first:

```
MainExample mainCl = new MainExample();
NextClass nextCl = new NextClass(mainCl);
```

In an instance method, you would do something like:

```
public NextClass createNextClass() {
    return new NextClass(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope when you mean `MainClass` you are referring to class `MainExample`

if thats the case 
you dont instance available implicitly by the JVM you have to create one explicitly

```
MainExample mainCl = new MainExample();
NextClass nextCl = new NextClass(mainCl);
```